# Did Heroku change its handling of double slash in paths?

Tags: heroku

Our Heroku-hosted service suddenly started to get requests for `//foo` instead of `/foo` yesterday; the service naturally 404'd the broken `//foo` version. It looks like a client of the service had been sending `//foo` all along, but somehow until about noon Eastern on July 23, the service was just seeing `/foo` so the client was working fine. But it broke once the service started to see `//foo`.

Did the Heroku router auto-fix `//foo` or something until yesterday?

Just trying to figure out what happened and ensure there's nothing else to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I assume there was a heroku router change because we noticed the same thing at around the same time. Our application had been receiving "//foo" for at least the last few months but the router had been logging and handling it as "/foo" up until around the time you mention.

Comment: I got this reply on twitter fwiw: https://twitter.com/dmathieu/status/492409584477564929